# can't get files for validaion data

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, google-colaboratory

that's my dataset i unzip it successfuly

```
zip_file = tf.keras.utils.get_file(origin='https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/1vRDbctiK6_FUj0RI6Sb1qDtuFUQG4UfB?alt=media&key=AIzaSyACfEqKwfF0knf66ORa7------', 
                               fname='PlantVillage.tar.zip', extract=True)
```

and i create the training and validation directories

```
data_dir = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(zip_file), 'PlantVillage')
train_dir = os.path.join(data_dir, 'train')
validation_dir = os.path.join(data_dir, 'validation')

import time
import os
from os.path import exists

def count(dir, counter=0):
"returns number of files in dir and subdirs"
for pack in os.walk(dir):
    for f in pack[2]:
        counter += 1
return dir + " : " + str(counter) + "files"
```

and the problem is here i get 0 files for train data and 0 too for valdiation data :

```
print('total images for training :', count(train_dir))
print('total images for validation :', count(validation_dir))
```

result:
total images for training : /root/.keras/datasets/PlantVillage/train : 0files

total images for validation : /root/.keras/datasets/PlantVillage/validation : 0files

Answer (score 0):

So from my understanding, you have unzipped and stored it in the `zip_file`. And then you created directories in that zip_file path, but you have not moved any files to these newly created directories (train_dir and validation_dir), hence there are no files under them. So it will help if you go and actually check on your local for the file hierarchy that has been created by the code execution.